# How to run an EXE file which has UI inside a Java program

Tags: java, automation, exe

I'm collecting samples from Output of a several programs. the number of sample files are too many and it is impossible to be done manually. I have to apply following steps for at least 20000 files:

1) open program{EXE-file which has UI}

2) give in an input file's path {like when you click on browse-file button}

3) run the program {like when you click on start-process button}

so I need to automatically be able to done it!

I already done the same for a command-line EXE program as describe in:{ [Run cmd commands through java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464111/run-cmd-commands-through-java)} but when you have a EXE-file-with-UI you can't just repeat a command in CMD an get results :(

thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be very complex, but not impossible (assuming windows since you have an exe).

First you will need to read up on the windows API.  It has functions to retrieve pointers to controls and activate them (see for example here: [how to programmatically click on a button in running app using C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705039/how-to-programmatically-click-on-a-button-in-running-app-using-c-sharp-code)) although that example is in C#.

Then you will need to use JNI or JNA to use the Windows API in your java application.

Combine the two and you can achieve what you need.